# changing elements with svg

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to control and manipulate an element within svg.

Basically I want the text to go small to big in the middle of the screen. This works if I'm using div class but if I put it within svg, the top part of the element goes off the screen.

```css
  .square {background-color: 
    white; width 10px; height: 
    30px; font-size: 10px; 
    color: green; text-align: 
    center;position: relative; 
    relative: 200px;}

    .square {animation: img 
    100s linear infinite } 
    @keyframes img  {

    from {

    transform: translate3d(0px, 
    0px, 10px) scale(.5);

    }

    to {

    transform: translate3d(0px, 
    0px, 10px) scale(170.8);

    }

    }

    svg {height: 100%; width: 
    100%;}
```

```html
    <svg viewBox="0 0 240 80"  
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/
    2000/svg">
  
    <style>
    .square {fill: green; 
    position: relative; top: 
    50px;} 
    </style>

    <text class="square">square</text>
    </svg>
```

Why isn't it taking instructions when I set element to `position: relative; top: 100px` with css?

I'm not sure so I tried to define it with style tag and, whilst this works for setting color, it doesn't work for positioning.

So how do I position my element where I want it because currently half of the word is off screen and I can't move it. In addition. Instead of going from small text to big text in a zoom like way in the middle of the screen, it's going small left of the screen to big right of the screen. Why how?

Comment: SVG elements don't support the CSS position property or top or left. Positioning depends on the element for text there are x and y attributes.

Comment: So could i do css `x{ position: relative; top: 50px;} ` also, do x and y only control position or something else too?

Comment: x is an attribute, not a CSS property. Perhaps start [here](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#SVG_Basics)

Comment: @RobertLongson so y="65" would move it 65px on the y axis?

Comment: Yes, do read the primer in the link above it will answer a lot of basic questions.

Comment: I've tried it but it seems to speed up the animation...

Comment: If your intention is to see better the text you can change the viewBox to `0 -50 240 80`